# Grantsmanship about Biology/NIH/NSF on Topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Would questions about grantsmanship pertaining to biology be appropriate here, or would Academia be the only location that was appropriate?

Strict grant questions certainly go over there, but how about NIH payline trends, protocols used on grants, etc (published information, not looking for anyone to spill the beans on the future)?

Perhaps there is no gray area, but I was thinking there might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would tend to think that unless the question is mainly about biology, most if not all grant questions should go to [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/). While grants are (unfortunately) a big part of life for most academic scientists, I can't find anything in the [Help Center](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help) that would support their being on-topic here.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I just wanted to be sure.  I was drafting my first Academia.SE question (on grants) and it had an awful lot of biology in it, which gave me pause.  I'm still thinking about rewording, and trying to trim all the science off that isn't absolutely necessary.  I may even try to split it into a few questions, on of which I could post over here.